# Update DataFrame index by matching column value

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following `pandas.DataFrame`:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
...     "sym": ["a", "b", "c"],
...     "del": [1, 2, 3]
... })
```

And consider the following `dict`:

```
>>> d = [{"sid": 99, "sym": "b"}, {"sid": 88, "sym": "c"}]
```

I need to update `df`'s index with the value of `sid` where `sym` matches. For this example, my output would like like this:

```
>>> df
   sym  del
0    a    1
99   b    2
88   c    3
```

How might I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with dictionary, then replace missing values by original index values:

```
d = [{"sid": 99, "sym": "b"}, {"sid": 88, "sym": "c"}]

d1 = {x['sym']:x['sid'] for x in d}
df.index = df['sym'].map(d1).fillna(df.index.to_series()).astype(int).rename(None)

print (df)
   sym  del
0    a    1
99   b    2
88   c    3
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "sym": ["a", "b", "c"],
   "del": [1, 2, 3]
}, index=[50,51,52])
print (df)
   sym  del
50   a    1
51   b    2
52   c    3

d = [{"sid": 99, "sym": "b"}, {"sid": 88, "sym": "c"}]

d1 = {x['sym']:x['sid'] for x in d}
df.index = df['sym'].map(d1).fillna(df.index.to_series()).astype(int).rename(None)

print (df)
   sym  del
50   a    1
99   b    2
88   c    3
```

Comment: This returns index as float, not int.

Comment: @Stuart - Hmmm, for me not.

Comment: This also will reset other indexes. Example if the indexes are [50, 51, 52] the example code will return indexes of [0, 51, 52]. Can only mutate the matching rows.

Comment: @JasonStrimpel - For me working correct, edited answer.

Comment: Yes I see what I did. Works well

Answer (score 1):

here is one way using `merge` after converting the list of dict to a dataframe:

```
m = df.merge(pd.DataFrame(d),on='sym',how='left')
df.index = m['sid'].fillna(df.index.to_series()).astype(int).rename(None)
print(df)
```

---

```
   sym  del
0    a    1
99   b    2
88   c    3
```